# Javascript fetch not working with http://key@www.example.com

Tags: javascript, http, typescript, fetch-api, http-status-code-401

I am trying to access a web-Api (Prestashops Web API to be exact) and fetch seems to have a problem with an url in this format : `http://SOMEKEY12345@www.example.com`. In both Chrome and Postman everything works perfectly fine but using the fetch-API I always get an `401` Error.

Here is my Typescript Code :

```
public fetchData() {
fetch("http://SOMEKEY1234@www.example.com").then((response : Response)=>{
  response.text().then((text : string) =>console.log(text));
})
```

Comment: If you check the actual request with Fiddler (or similar) has anything been altered? You could run one Postman request and one fetch request and compare both requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fetch API doesn’t allow a URL in the form `http://SOMEKEY1234@www.example.com` to be used in requests. Specifically, it doesn’t let you to use an "`@`" character before the hostname.

If you use such a URL, it’s interpreted as providing username/password credentials, and [the Fetch spec requires browsers to throw a `TypeError`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-request) (and thus to halt the request):

> The `Request(input, init)` constructor must run these steps:
>   …
>   If *parsedURL* [includes credentials](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#include-credentials), then throw a `TypeError`.

The only solution is to not put credentials in the request URL in the way (that is, don’t have a "`@`" character before the hostname in the request URL).